# URL não mostra símbolos

Tags: html, html5

Eu tenho um site que envia uma URL assim:

`site.com.br/test.php?s=<p>texto</p>`

A variável `s` é usada pela página `test.php` para imprimir um PDF.

Mas no computador do cliente está aparecendo assim:

`site.com.br/test.php?s=%3Cp%3Etexto%3C/p%3E` e não funciona a impressão.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Isso aconteceu porque é necessário codificar os caracteres `<` e `>` por `%3C` e `%3E` respectivamente para poder transmiti-los pela internet.

Uma URL só pode ter caracteres em ASCII por isso essa codificação é necessária.

Veja esta tabela: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Já enviei dados com tags HTML pelo método GET e a exibição foi efetuada normalmente, tente enviar os dados pelo método POST, caso não resolva poste o código do formulário e do que recebe os dados para imprimir.

Answer (score 1):

Isso se chama codificação de URL e serve para evitar conflito entre o **conteúdo** da URL com caracteres de controle. Por exemplo, analisadores de URL utilizam a barra, `/`, para delimitar os segmentos do *path*, assim como utilizam o ponto de interrogação, `?`, para iniciar a *query string* e a cerquilha, `#`, para iniciar o fragmento. Se o seu conteúdo possuir esses caracteres a sintaxe da URL pode ser prejudicada e, assim, mal interpretada.

Por exemplo, se eu quero enviar a expressão lógica `a & b = c` pela URL e fizer:

```
https://localhost/query?s=a&b=c
```

A *query string* será interpretada como `s=a` e `b=c`, que não tem nenhuma relação com a nossa intenção. Por isso ela deve ser codificada:

```
https://localhost/query?s=%3Fs%3Da%26b%3Dc
```

E, desta forma, não haverá redundância e, portanto, a URL será interpretada corretamente.

Assim, se a impressão está sendo afetada pela codificação, precisa rever o que está fazendo. Suas opções triviais seriam: 1) Decodificar corretamente a URL antes de utilizar para gerar o PDF; 2) Enviar o conteúdo pelo corpo da requisição HTTP e não pela URL.

Eu recomendaria a segunda opção.

Answer (score 0):

As URLs não suportam alguns caracteres especiais, que acabam convertidos pelo cliente (navegador, aplicativo, etc) no momento de realizar uma requisição HTTP. As duas URLs que você informou são equivalentes (após encode-decode), como você pode conferir [neste conversor](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/). A tabela de conversão de caracteres está disponível [neste link](http://www.codex.wiki.br/Html/URLEncodeRefer%C3%AAncia).

No PHP você deve ler sua variável utilizando o método [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php).